# set timeout to http response read method in python

Tags: python, timeout, httpresponse

I'm building a download manager in python for fun, and sometimes the connection to the server is still on but the server doesn't send me data, so read method (of HTTPResponse) block me forever. This happens, for example, when I download from a server, which located outside of my country, that limit the bandwidth to other countries.

How can I set a timeout for the read method (2 minutes for example)?

Thanks, Nir.

Comment: related: [Read timeout using either urllib2 or any other http library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9548869/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it during [HTTPConnection](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection) initialization.

Note: in case you are using an older version of Python, then you can install [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/); by many, it is considered a superior alternative to httplib, and it does supports [timeout](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#httplib2.Http).
I've never used it, though, and I'm just reporting what documentation and blogs are saying.

Comment: +1, but note the timeout parameter to the constructor is available only in python 2.6+.

Comment: Right - I've added some notes about httplib2

Comment: I will try it, but I'm a little bit skeptic because the code of HTTPResponse class use the 'makefile' method, which cannot get a timeout by the documentation: "The socket must be in blocking mode (it can not have a timeout)".

Answer (score 3):

If you're stuck on some Python version `< 2.6`, one (imperfect but usable) approach is to do

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10.0)  # or whatever
```

before you start using `httplib`.  The docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.setdefaulttimeout), and clearly state that `setdefaulttimeout` is available since Python 2.3 -- every socket made from the time you do this call, to the time you call the same function again, will use that timeout of 10 seconds.  You can use [getdefaulttimeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.getdefaulttimeout) before setting a new timeout, if you want to save the previous timeout (including none) so that you can restore it later (with another `setdefaulttimeout`).

These functions and idioms are quite useful whenever you need to use some older higher-level library which uses Python `socket`s but doesn't give you a good way to set timeouts (of course it's better to use updated higher-level libraries, e.g. the `httplib` version that comes with 2.6 or the third-party `httplib2` in this case, but that's not always feasible, and playing with the default timeout setting can be a good workaround).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the default timeout might abort a download early if it's large, as opposed to only aborting if it stops receiving data for the timeout value. HTTPlib2 is probably the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

5 years later but hopefully this will help someone else...

I was wrecking my brain trying to figure this out. My problem was a server returning corrupt content and thus giving back less data than it thought it had.

I came up with a nasty solution that seems to be working properly. Here it goes:

```
# NOTE I directly disabling blocking is not necessary but it represents
# an important piece to the problem so I am leaving it here.
# http_response.fp._sock.socket.setblocking(0)
http_response.fp._sock.settimeout(read_timeout)
http_response.read(chunk_size)
```

**NOTE** This solution also works for <s>the python requests</s> **ANY** library that implements the normal python sockets (which should be all of them?). You just have to go a few levels deeper:

```
resp.raw._fp.fp._sock.socket.setblocking()
resp.raw._fp.fp._sock.settimeout(read_timeout)
resp.raw.read(chunk_size)
```

As of this writing, I have not tried the following but in theory it should work:

```
resp = requests.get(some_url, stream=True)
resp.raw._fp.fp._sock.socket.setblocking()
resp.raw._fp.fp._sock.settimeout(read_timeout)
for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size):
      # do stuff
```

**Explanation**

I stumbled upon this approach when reading this SO question for [setting a timeout on socket.recv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2719017/1991100)

At the end of the day, any http request has a socket. For the httplib that socket is located at `resp.raw._fp.fp._sock.socket`. The `resp.raw._fp.fp._sock` is a `socket._fileobj` (which I honestly didn't look far into) and I imagine it's `settimeout` method internally sets it on the `socket` attribute.

Comment: If you're going to downvote an answer at least give a guy a reason.