# Python: Stop the socket-receiving-process

Tags: python, interrupt, break, recv

I receive data from some device via socket-module.
But after some time the device stops sending packages.
Then I want to interupt the for-loop.
While True doesn't work, because he receives more then 100 packages.
How can I stop this process?
s stands for socket.

```
...
for i in range(packages100):
    data = s.recv(4)
    f.write(data)
...
```

Edit:
I think socket.settimeout() is part of the solution. See also:
[How to set timeout on python's socket recv method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719017/how-to-set-timeout-on-pythons-socket-recv-method)

Comment: Is not there a way to find out how many packages the client will want to recv?

Comment: Stopping the process is not the problem. The problem is deciding when to do so. What are the criteria?

Comment: I want to stop the process after one second without receiving data.

Answer (score 3):

If your peer really just stops sending data, as opposed to closing the connection, this is tricky and you'll be forced to resort to asynchronous reading from this socket.

Put it in asynchronous mode (the docs and Google are your friends), and try to read it each time, instead of the blocking read. You can then just stop "trying" anytime you wish. Note that by nature of async IO your code will be a bit different - you will no longer be able to assume that once `recv` returns, it actually read some data.

Answer (score 2):

```
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(4)
    if not data: break
    f.write(data)
```

Also, [example in python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/socket-example.html)

Comment: Ahh, I see. So "the device stops sending packages" is not equivalent to closing the con.

Comment: Well, maybe and maybe not, I can't be sure what the OP means. I just wanted to point out the difference