# Throw Socket Timeout for recv

Tags: python, network-programming, timeout

I have been looking, here: [How to set timeout on python's socket recv method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719017/how-to-set-timeout-on-pythons-socket-recv-method)

And others, but I cannot seem to get it working like I want. I am writing a traceroute script and want to the program to throw a timeout exception if it has been waiting for more than 10 seconds for a reply from the packet it just sent so it can move to the next hop. I have a couple extra except's to try and catch the timeout, but it never catches (or even throws) the exception.

```
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
    #setup receive socket
    recv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    recv_socket.bind(("", 8888))
    #recv_socket.settimeout(10)
    recv_socket.setblocking(0)
    ready = select.select([recv_socket], [], [], 10)
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
 
# tell kernel not to put in headers, when using IPPROTO_RAW this is not necessary
# s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# Get usable hostname
destination_address = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
max_ttl = 50
ttl = 1

while(1):
    # Timer
    t_start = time.time()

    s.sendto(constructPacket(ttl,'129.196.196.163',destination_address), (destination_address , 0 )) 
    
    # Receive and output
    # need to add, if no receive, timeout and increase ttl by one
    curr_addr = None
    curr_name = None
    try:
        if ready[0]:
            _, curr_addr = recv_socket.recvfrom(512)
            curr_addr = curr_addr[0]
        else:
            print 'Timeout'
        try:
            curr_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(curr_addr)[0]
        except socket.error:
            curr_name = curr_addr
    except timeout, e:
        print 'Timeout'
    except socket.error, e:
        print 'Socket Error. Error Code : ' + str(e[0]) + ' Message ' + e[1]
        sys.exit()

    if curr_addr is not None:
        curr_host = "%s (%s)" % (curr_name, curr_addr)
    else:
        curr_host = "*"
    print "%d | %s | %dms" % (ttl, curr_host,(time.time()-t_start)*1000)

    ttl = ttl + 1

    if curr_addr == destination_address or ttl == max_ttl:
        s.close()
        recv_socket.close()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no timeout exceptions in non-blocking mode. Use a timeout argument to `select()`, and detect the case where `select()` returns without any ready sockets.