# Tkinter .after method freezing window?

Tags: python, sockets, events, tkinter

I have a simple chat client that I was attempting to get working with `Tkinter` as the interface.  My problem is that when running the `mainloop` with `.after` for the chat input/output, the window freezes and blocks until another message is received.

```
class Client(Frame):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, Tk())
        self.pack()

        self.lb = Listbox(self, width=100, height=30)
        self.lb.pack()

        self.show_data = self.lb.after(1000, self.chat_handle)

        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.input_handle)
        self.entry.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def input_handle(self, event):
        msg = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        new_msg = 'privmsg %s :' % self.channel + msg + '\r\n'
        self.client.sendall(new_msg)
        self.lb.insert(END, self.nick + ' | ' + msg)

    def chat_handle(self):
        try:
            self.data = self.client.recvfrom(1024)
        except socket.error:
            self.lb.insert(END, "Bad Connection!")
            return
        if self.data and len(self.data[0]) > 0:
            self.lb.insert(END, self.data[0])
        elif self.data and len(self.data[0]) == 0:
            self.lb.insert(END, "Connection Dropped!")
            return
        self.show_data = self.lb.after(1000, self.chat_handle)
```

This block of code is shortened but, shows the relavent parts involved.  The `Entry` widget will become unresponsive for extended periods while `.after` is called and won't respond until a message is received.

When the `Entry` widget becomes responsive again, the entry field has all the data that was typed in but, I won't see the changes during the "frozen" time. The same goes for the `Listbox` widget.

If anyone could shed some light on why this is exactly or point out if I'm miss using a method here, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: after some more research, its looking like the `socket` data is blocking whenever its called and window is getting frozen during this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned about using `select` to make system calls to check if a socket file is ready to be read.

[How to set timeout on python's socket recv method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719017/how-to-set-timeout-on-pythons-socket-recv-method)

```
class Client(Frame):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.connect(("host", port))
        self.client.setblocking(0)
        Frame.__init__(self, Tk())
        self.pack()

        self.lb = Listbox(self, width=100, height=30)
        self.lb.pack()

        self.show_data = self.lb.after(1000, self.chat_handle)

        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.input_handle)
        self.entry.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def input_handle(self, event):
        msg = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        new_msg = 'privmsg %s :' % self.channel + msg + '\r\n'
        self.client.sendall(new_msg)
        self.lb.insert(END, self.nick + ' | ' + msg)

    def chat_handle(self):
        socket_data = select.select([self.client], [], [], 0.3) # set timeout on last arg
        if socket_data[0]:
            try:
                self.data = self.client.recvfrom(1024)
            except socket.error:
                self.lb.insert(END, "Bad Connection!")
                return
            if self.data and len(self.data[0]) > 0:
                self.lb.insert(END, self.data[0])
            elif self.data and len(self.data[0]) == 0:
                self.lb.insert(END, "Connection Dropped!")
                return
            self.show_data = self.lb.after(1000, self.chat_hand
```

Answer (score 6):

`after` executes the callback function after the given time; however, this method also runs in the main thread. So if there is an operation that takes more time than usual (in this case, the blocking `recvfrom`), the GUI will be unresponsive until the complete callback is executed.

To solve this, a common recipe is to spawn a new thread and communicate it with your Tkinter code with a synchronized object like a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). Thus, you put the data in the queue when you receive it from the socket, and then check periodically in the main thread inside the `after` callback.

This is a question whose answer can be adapted to use the same approach: [Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from "freezing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing/16747734#16747734)

Comment: thanks for the response and link.  I'm reading up on non-blocking sockets right now too.

Comment: I went with `select` here but, I'm going to make a version that uses the `Queue` module with threads too.

Comment: To be completely clear:  it's not the `after()` method *itself* that is freezing things up, it's the callback.  E.g. you can execute an `after()` with a delay of (say) 10 seconds, and for those 10 seconds everything will continue normally.  But if the callback causes blocking or consumes excess resources, *then* the GUI will freeze.  (Just wanted to note this as I was temporarily confused, thinking that if I put an `after()` call in my code, no lines following that `after()` would execute until the time expired.)