# Trying to execute a set of functions in order

Tags: python, timer, tkinter

I am a Python noob, and I'm trying to make a washing device, programming the interface with Python. For now, the machine should work like that:

1. Wash
2. Tell washing is complete
3. Dry
4. Tell drying is complete

For this, after times for washing/drying are entered, a button is pressed:

```
button1 = Button(window.tk, command = lambda:main_process(int(varWashtime.get()), int(varDrytime.get())))

def main_process(wash_seconds,dry_seconds):
        wash(wash_seconds)
        stop_wash()
        dry(dry_seconds)
        stop_dry()
        return

def wash(seconds):
    varWashStarted.set("Washing Started") 
    Timer(seconds,idle_fnc).start() 
    return

def stop_wash():
    varWashStarted.set("Washing Stopped")
    Timer(3,idle_fnc,()).start()
    return

def dry(seconds):
    varDryStarted.set("Drying Started")
    Timer(seconds,idle_fnc,()).start()
    return

def stop_dry():
    varDryStarted.set("Drying Stopped")
    return

def idle_fnc():
    pass
    return
```

Here, I used the function `idle_fnc` to make `threading.Timer` properly work.

I found out that I can just use Timer to call other functions after each other, but I would prefer to return from a function, then branch to a new one.

My problem is, as I click the button, the whole thing executes without waiting; I instantly see "Washing Stopped" and "Drying Stopped" on the corresponding label, without the delays triggered.

What is the problem?

Comment: Your lines `Timer(seconds,idle_fnc).start()` are not blocking.  They just start a thread but the main thread goes on.  So your 4 functions are executed consecutively.

Comment: @S.deMelo What is the alternative here, else than `time.sleep()` ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887729/time-delay-tkinter

Comment: Tried that, and it blocks program execution, just like `time.sleep()`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you have to use a thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17016127/6919239

Comment: Yeah, that seems useful, checking it now. Many thanks :)

Comment: @S.deMelo: absolutely not. Threads are definitely the _wrong_ solution here if all you're doing is waiting for a period of time.

Comment: search this site for uses of the `after` method on widgets. It lets you schedule some function to run in the future.