# Implementing a non-blocking TCP Server

Tags: python, tcp, nonblocking

I am trying to implement a TCP server which will not hang (potentially) forever during a recv or sendall operation.

I thought it would be enough to specify a timeout for the active socket, but this seems not to be the case: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719017/how-to-set-timeout-on-pythons-socket-recv-method)

So, how could I extend my code to ensure that:

> - recv will not hang up in any case
> - sendall will not hang up in any cases (well, I am not sure if sendall can hang up at all)

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `select` function.
It takes 3 arguments; read list, write list, error list.
And then it returns three values, each being a list of the socket that you inputted that are ready to be either be written to, read from. ( Or has had an error if you wanted to check for that. )

```
rl , wl , el = select( [ serversocket , clientsocket ] , [] , [] );
for e in rl:
  if e == serversocket:
    acceptConnection( serversocket );
  else:
    readFromClient( clientsocket );
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you answer. Does this this also take care that sendall will not hang up? Do I not need to make the active socket non-blocking?

Comment: You want to go into non blocking mode for `sendall`, but before you write to it next time, make sure to check if you can write to it yet with `select`.

Comment: You do not need to make the socket nonblocking. Select tells zou if something is there and then you can start to read/write

Comment: The reason you want to go into non-blocking mode is so that you don't have to wait for large chunks of data being sent before moving on in the program flow.

Comment: However, when using select, do I have issues with the server getting stucked if the client crashes, and doesn't shut down the socket properly? If the crash happend after the select operation...

Comment: You just need to catch any exception coming your way, and then disconnect the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this. But where is the best place to insert your code? In the final while loop or within handler?