# reading from socket python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm new to python and socket programming, and trying to scan a port of a WAN address.

I know from using nmap that he has port 80 and 443 open.

Why can't I read from it to see if it's open??? Also, when I scan my gateway with my program it shows that 21 and 23 are open which is what NMAP shows me. BUT nmap also tells me I have port 80 and 443 as well, yet my program doesn't pick those up.

Thanks

```
def return_banner(ip, port):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip, port)) #establish connection
        banner = s.recv(1024) #receive the first 1024 bytes from socket
        return banner
    except:
        return #will return none

def main():
lan_or_wan()
dictionary_of_open_services = {}
list_of_ports = [20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 80, 8080, 53, 67, 68, 443, 993, 143, 110]
list_of_ports.sort()
if (local == False):
    print "local = false"
    for port in list_of_ports:
        print "scanning: "+WAN_IP+":"+str(port)
        software_banner = return_banner(WAN_IP, port)
        if (software_banner != None):
            dictionary_of_open_services[WAN_IP+":"+str(port)] = software_banner
```

Comment: Given your use case, you *shouldn't* handle a timeout on connection as the same as a timeout on read: the former might indicate a filtered port. The later denotes an open port whose associated service does not send a banner. Two completely different things. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719017/how-to-set-timeout-on-pythons-socket-recv-method for some solutions

Comment: So I should remove that socket.setdefaultimeout(2) then?

Answer (score 0):

Since no request is made, the connection is connected but idle. `socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)` gives a timeout error, hence `None` is returned. To grab the banner, certain request must be made.

To just check the port open, try connecting the port. If connection is successful return True else return False.

```
    try:
        s.connect((ip, port))
        s.close()
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: _"To grab the banner, certain request must be made."_ Not necessary. Some services might spontaneously send a banner on connection. But I agree, _usually_, banner grabbing is done by sending some garbage on the port to get gather informations from the server "error message".

Comment: @SylvainLeroux that's why his scripts shows 21 and 23 are open but 80 and 443 are closed.

Comment: Right: to check that, use telnet: `telnet localhot 21` should show you a banner (sometimes simply the login prompt) without further action. OTOH, `telnet localhost 80` should display a "blank" screen, until you actually send something to the server.

Comment: @srekcahrai is this what you mean about connecting and checking connection is successful?
            `s = socket.socket() #create port`
            `s.bind(("", 12345)) #bind to my own port`
            `s.listen(5) #listen to port`
            `result = s.connect_ex((ip, port)) #establish connection`
            `#then check the result?`