# python socket / how do you detect disconnection from clients and detect number of connections per user

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket, python-sockets

this is for server authentication for my application.
(im working on login function so dont mind about it)
what i wanna do is to make server receive heartbeat from client
and close client socket if its doesnt respond in a few min
also i want to detect number of connections per user.

for receiving heartbeat, i can make the client send heartbeat constantly but
how do you make the server decect it? i know time measurement is needed but
if i put time.perf_counter() right before 'client_socket.recv(1024)' the counter function wont be executed because its waiting on receiving. so how would i solve this?

and im also trying to make it detect number of connections per user. (5 maximum connections per user) for detection, i give username + 1 when a user is connected and give -1 when the user disconnects but im not sure if the method im doing is correct or a good way to do so.

i'd be appreciated if you could help me out

```
------------------------server----------------------------    

import socket 
from _thread import *
import sys
import time


username = ['test123', 'hongengi']
userconnect= 0


def threaded(client_socket, addr): 
    print('Connected by :', addr[0], ':', addr[1]) 


    while True: 

        try:

            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            print (data.decode())
            print('Received from ' + addr[0],':',addr[1] , data.decode())

            if data.decode() == ".": # heartbeat
                heartbeat = time.perf_counter()
                print ("heartbeat")

            if data.decode() == "test123":
                print ("login success")
                userconnect == userconnect + 1    
                
            
            if not data:
                print ("no data / disconnect ")
                print('Disconnected by ' + addr[0],':',addr[1])
                userconnect == userconnect - 1 
                break

            client_socket.send(data) 

        except (ConnectionResetError, socket.error) as e:
            print ("error occurs")

            print('Disconnected by ' + addr[0],':',addr[1])
            userconnect == userconnect - 1 
            break
             
    client_socket.close() 


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT)) 
server_socket.listen() 

print('server start')


while True: 

    print('wait')


    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept() 
    start_new_thread(threaded, (client_socket, addr)) 

server_socket.close()





------------------------client---------------------------- 

import socket

SERVER_IP = 'localhost'
SERVER_PORT = 5000
SIZE = 100
SERVER_ADDR = (SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
heartbeat = "."
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(SERVER_ADDR)
#username = "test123"
#userpass = "123123"

while True:

    client_socket.send(heartbeat.encode())
    msg = client_socket.recv(SIZE)
    print (msg.decode())
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One end of a socket is never "notified" when the other socket closes.  There is no direct connection, so the only way to tell this is to time out.  You can use `socket.timeout` to establish a timeout time.  Your `recv` will then return with 0 bytes, and that's an indication that your timeout expired.

[How to set timeout on python's socket recv method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719017/how-to-set-timeout-on-pythons-socket-recv-method)